# Unable to add space above navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm trying to add a space above my navigation bar, however the code I'm using is failing to do so.

#### My CSS

```
.top-nav ul {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.top-nav  li {
    display:inline;
}
.top-nav a {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.top-nav  ul a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.top-nav  ul a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
```

#### A Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/xuk2nk46/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.top-nav {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: While this answer may be technically correct, it is of very low quality. Explain why your solution fixes the problem!

Answer (score 0):

u have given two values to top-padding

```
.top-nav a {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

and
.

```
top-nav  ul a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 10px;}
```

the second one is applied which is 0 px

Comment: Changed it to: .top-nav  ul a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}  but still nothing & I also have removed the first padding-top rule

Answer (score 0):

```
.top-nav{
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

and remove the padding , or keep only one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `margin-top` to `.top-nav`:

```
.top-nav {
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

`Margin` adds a space outside the element, while `padding` adds a space inside the element.

Answer (score 0):

By default `<a>` in an `inline` element. So `padding` with `top` and `bottom` values won't apply.

You have to change the default type by `inline-block` to add `top` and `bottom` `padding` on it.

Also, you can group this two properties `.top-nav a` and `.top-nav  ul a` together like this :

```
.top-nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

And then, you can set top and bottom padding values with this property :  `padding: 20px 10px;` or use margin property like this `margin: 20px 10px;`

Answer (score 0):

Just add a margin to your `.top-nav` :

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans);

*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
}

.top-nav {
    margin: 30px 0 0 0; /* ADD MARGIN HERE */
}

.top-nav ul {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.top-nav  li {
    display:inline;
}
.top-nav a {
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.top-nav  ul a {
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.top-nav  ul a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top-nav">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="index.html">Store</a></li>
       <li><a href="index.html">Blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="index.html" id="btn-special">Join Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xuk2nk46/2/))